# Theme directory path in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I saw this website to get the path of the theme where the files are: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo

And I have a form (file register.php) that sends a post to a file (register_proc.php) in the same directory.

```
<form id = "form" name = "form" method = "post" action = "<?php echo get_option ('template_url');? > /register_proc.php ">
```

The two files are in: wp-content/themes/theme_name .

But when I submit the link in browser is "http://127.0.0.1/register_proc.php" and it says the file is not found. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `get_bloginfo('template_url')` instead of `get_option('template_url')`

Comment: Sorry, but it was to copy from a file to another and it must have happened .. but obviously this is not the problem

Comment: Fair enough. I focused on the syntax errors rather than the misuse of get_option(). By the way, you also have a space in your closing php tag.